# Hover effect not working on positioned Anchor Tag <a>

Tags: css, hover

When I position the element above an image Hover effect stop working.
Any idea why? I'm learning.

I have some positioned elements, an overlay with opacity on top of a div with a background image in fixed position.

Code entire section and entire CSS :

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- Global Wrapper -->
<section>
    <div class="first-row">
       <div class="first-row__overlay">
       </div>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2 class="jumbotron__header">This is the Title</h2>
            <p class="jumbotron__text">Lorem text
            </p>
            <div class="under-line"></div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="my-Btn">START NOW</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arsenal', sans-serif;
  }
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
.first-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("../images/paradise-1.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  }
.first-row__overlay {
  background-color: rgba(33, 46, 63, 1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: .35;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
  }
.jumbotron { 
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: -70vh;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
.under-line {
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  transition: 7s ease;
 }
.my-Btn {
 position: relative;
  top: -67vh;
  z-index: 99999999;
  color: #1d1e1f;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  background-color: #fdfdfe;
  border-radius: 30px;
  }
.my-Btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Comment: Please share your entire code. It would be helpful. Or the part with image and anchor link.

Comment: I did fixed by placing the html code of the anchor tag outside the section. But Im still wondering why inside the <section> is not working the hover effect, also doesnt work when I try to target the selector with jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a z-index set to negative position, `z-index: -100`, remove that from `.first-row` class and it will resolve the issue. You need to keep an eye on the z-indexing, always think of the elements as a stack which lives on top of each other.

```
.first-row {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: url("../images/paradise-1.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center;
      background-size: cover;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes sure, as soon as I learn how to do up vote,, haha Im learning.. let me see.

Comment: You may not have the privilege yet.